# Edittext hidden by softkeyboard

Tags: android

i have created a layout programmatically and set it into secontentview  within oncreate i am create chat layout using simple edittext and a send image button right from edittext whenever user click on edittext suddenly hide by softkeyboard i tried all option which is required to mention in menifest like adjustPan or screenresize etc but no effect the edittext still hidden by keyboard

here is my layout code that contain the edittext

```
private LinearLayout getTextChatViewTest() {
//      MainActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
//  LibraryMainActivity.this.getActionBar().show();

    LinearLayout linWrapperLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linWrapperLayoutParams;

    LinearLayout linHeaderLayout;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linHeaderParams;
    TextView txtHeaderText;

    linWrapperLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    linWrapperLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linWrapperLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    linWrapperLayout.setLayoutParams(linWrapperLayoutParams);
    linWrapperLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    linHeaderLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    linHeaderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3E9F3"));
    linHeaderLayout.setPadding(pixToDp(10), pixToDp(5), pixToDp(10), pixToDp(5));
    linHeaderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linHeaderLayout.setLayoutParams(linHeaderParams);

    txtHeaderText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txtHeaderText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
    txtHeaderText.setPadding(pixToDp(5), pixToDp(10), pixToDp(10), pixToDp(10));
    txtHeaderText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#004A8F"));
    linHeaderLayout.addView(txtHeaderText);
    txtHeaderText.setText("Text Chat");

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relPArams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rel.setLayoutParams(relPArams);
    linWrapperLayout.addView(rel);
    rel.addView(linHeaderLayout);

    txtChatArea = new TextView(MainActivity.this);


    txtChatArea.setId(011);
    txtChatArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    txtChatArea.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    int scroll_amount = (int) (txtChatArea.getLineCount() * txtChatArea.getLineHeight()) - (txtChatArea.getBottom() - txtChatArea.getTop());

    txtChatArea.setLinksClickable(true);
    txtChatArea.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    txtChatArea.setText("Anything");
    txtChatArea.scrollTo(0, scroll_amount);
    txtChatArea.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
    txtChatArea.setScrollY(0);
    txtChatArea.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    /** for allowing copy from text chat area */
    txtChatArea.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            txtChatArea.setCursorVisible(true);
            return true;
        }
    });


//  Button btn = new Button (this);
    android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
//  btn.setHeight((int)(display.getHeight()*0.68));

    int height = display.getHeight(); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relImageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                 (MainActivity.getPixelHeight(MainActivity.this))/2+60);
    relImageParams.setMargins(pixToDp(15), pixToDp(100),  pixToDp(15), 0);
    relImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 111);
    txtChatArea.setLayoutParams(relImageParams);
    rel.addView(txtChatArea);




    /* The following section was copied from incoming call view */
    relIncomingBottomLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    relIncomingBottomLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relIncomingBottomLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    //relIncomingBottomLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 011);
    relIncomingBottomLayoutParams.setMargins(pixToDp(10), 0, pixToDp(10), pixToDp(10));
    relIncomingBottomLayout.setLayoutParams(relIncomingBottomLayoutParams);
    rel.addView(relIncomingBottomLayout);


    /* Now add a linearlayout with vertical orientation, which will contain two linearlayouts with horizontal orientation */
    LinearLayout linBottomHolder = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    linBottomHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linHolderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linBottomHolder.setLayoutParams(linHolderParams);
    relIncomingBottomLayout.addView(linBottomHolder);

    /* an warning view on characters left for end users */
    txtWarning = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txtWarning.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    txtWarning.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
    txtWarning.setText("150 characters left");
    txtWarning.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    linBottomHolder.addView(txtWarning);

    /* Now add the first linear layout to contain an edittext to get message and an imageview */
    LinearLayout linWriteHolder = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    linWriteHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linWriteHolderPArams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    linWriteHolder.setLayoutParams(linWriteHolderPArams);
    linBottomHolder.addView(linWriteHolder);

    /* Now add an edittext and an imageview inside this linearlayout */
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#E3E9F3"));
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gd.setCornerRadius(5);
    edtWriteMesage = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    edtWriteMesage.setHint("Type text here");
    edtWriteMesage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    edtWriteMesage.setBackground(gd);
    edtWriteMesage.setSingleLine(true);

    /** filtering inputs */
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(150);
    edtWriteMesage.setFilters(filters); /** now a maximum of 150 characters can be taken as input */

    edtWriteMesage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int currentLength = edtWriteMesage.getText().toString().length();
            int remainingLength = 150 - currentLength;
            if(remainingLength <= 15){
                txtWarning.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                txtWarning.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            txtWarning.setText(""+remainingLength + " characters left");
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linWriteParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.9f);
    linWriteParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    edtWriteMesage.setLayoutParams(linWriteParams);
    linWriteHolder.addView(edtWriteMesage);

    /* Now add an imageview with an arrow in it by the edittext's side */
    imgSendArrow = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    byte[] sendArrow = Base64.decode(SecondImageStore.send, Base64.DEFAULT);
    //byte[] sendArrow = Base64.decode(SecondImageStore.papersend, Base64.DEFAULT);

    imgSendArrow.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(sendArrow, 0, sendArrow.length));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linSendParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                                              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f);
    linSendParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    linSendParams.setMargins(pxToDp(3), 0, pxToDp(2), 0);

    imgSendArrow.setLayoutParams(linSendParams);
    linWriteHolder.addView(imgSendArrow);


    /* Now add the Second relative layout to contain two buttons */
    LinearLayout linTextChatButtonHolder = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linTextChatButtonHolderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    linTextChatButtonHolderParams.setMargins(0, pixToDp(10), 0, 0);
    linTextChatButtonHolder.setLayoutParams(linTextChatButtonHolderParams);
    linBottomHolder.addView(linTextChatButtonHolder);






    /* Button to end ongoing conference */
    btnTextChatEndCall = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    btnTextChatEndCall.setText("Call Held");
    btnTextChatEndCall.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C11E0F"));
    btnTextChatEndCall.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
    btnTextChatEndCall.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnTextChatEndCall.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linTextChatEndCallParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
    linTextChatEndCallParams.setMargins(0, pixToDp(10), 0, 0);
    btnTextChatEndCall.setLayoutParams(linTextChatEndCallParams);
    linTextChatButtonHolder.addView(btnTextChatEndCall);

    /* Button to display menu in chat mode */
    btnTextChatMenu = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    btnTextChatMenu.setText("Menu");
    btnTextChatMenu.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnTextChatMenu.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#014A8E"));
    btnTextChatMenu.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
    btnTextChatMenu.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linTextChatMenuParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
    linTextChatMenuParams.setMargins(pixToDp(10), pixToDp(10), 0, 0);
    btnTextChatMenu.setLayoutParams(linTextChatMenuParams);
    linTextChatButtonHolder.addView(btnTextChatMenu);


    btnTextChatEndCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });




    edtWriteMesage.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
            switch (result) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:

                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return linWrapperLayout;
//   setContentView(linWrapperLayout);
    }
```

Comment: I think try to put the layout inside a scrollview user can scroll if the edittext is hidden.

Comment: @user3471185 : Please post your layout that contains 'edittext'.!

Comment: PLease post your xml

Comment: have u tried this ?

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

Comment: i  posted my code i am not using xml all view i have created using java code programmatically and set it into setContainView

Comment: i tried  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" within manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way to hide keyboard

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

}

Comment: as i need to show edittext above the softkeyboard wheneve user click on edittext the edittext placed bottom of layout along with other view

Comment: still no effect but when i use same dynamic layout with a separate application that is  working fine for any help i will be thankful

Comment: set in manifest file   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

In your `Manifest.xml` add this to you activity

```
 <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" ... >
        ...
 </activity>
```

for [Click here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) for more details about handling Input Methods

Answer (score 0):

```
i have just remove getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); after that edittext comming below the edittext whenever soft keyboard appear
```